# Perfect squares between certain divisors of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. We will call a divisor $d(<\sqrt{n})$ of $n$ *special* if there exists **no** perfect squares between $d$ and $\frac{n}{d}$. Prove that $n$ can have at-most one special divisor.

**My progress:** I boiled down the problem to the following:
Suppose $n^2\le a,b,c,d\le (n+1)^2$, then $ab=cd\implies \{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$. But I can't seem to prove this.

Arriving here isn't difficult so I am omitting any further details(one more reason being I am not sure if I am on the correct path).

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355600/perfect-squares-between-certain-divisors-of-a-number?noredirect=1#comment892312_355600 without notice to either site. That's an abuse.

Answer (score 2):

from $ab=cd$, there exist $x,y,z,t$ such that: $a=xy,b=zt,c=xz,d=yt$, if two of $x,y,z,t$ are equal then $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$, so i assume $x,y,z,t$ are distinct numbers

Wlog, assume $x=min\{x,y,z,t\}$ and $y<z$ , we have $n^2\le xy,xz,zt,yt\le (n+1)^2$

so $n^2\le xz<z^2$ then $z\ge n+1$, $y\ge n+1$ in the same way, so $M=max\{y,z\}>m=min\{y,z\}\ge n+1$

$(n+1)^2-n^2\ge max\{y,z\}.t-min\{y,z\}.x\ge (n+1)(t-x)$, so $t=x+1$

We get $\frac{n^2}{m}\le x$ and $x+1\le \frac{(n+1)^2}{M}$ so $\frac{n^2}{m}\le  \frac{(n+1)^2}{M}-1$ which lead us to $0\ge (M-m)n^2-2m.n+m(M-1)\ge n^2-2m.n+m^2=(n-m)^2>0 $ (contradiction), we are done here